# How to add if else into PHP code?

Tags: php

I have 4 social icons and if all of them weren't available then I want to show **default.jpg** , currently in the column, it's showing 5 icons including default.jpg too.

I added **$icons_available**, but not working, here is my complete code:

```
    <?php
    $icons_available = (
    !empty($rec->telegram) &&
    !empty($rec->google_plus) &&
    !empty($rec->instagram) &&
    !empty($rec->facebook)
    );
    ?>
    <td>
    <?php if(!$icons_available) {?><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/default.jpg" /><?php }?>
    <?php if($rec->telegram){ ?><a href="<?php echo $rec->telegram;  ?>"><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/telegram.jpg" /><?php } ?></a>
    <?php if($rec->google_pluse){ ?><a href="<?php echo $rec->google_pluse;  ?>"><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/g.jpg" /><?php } ?></a>
    <?php if($rec->instagram){ ?><a href="<?php echo $rec->instagram;  ?>"><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/insta.jpg" /><?php } ?></a>
    <?php if($rec->facebook){ ?><a href="<?php echo $rec->facebook;  ?>"><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/f.jpg" /><?php } ?></a>
    </td>
```

Here is my question:

**

> If all of 4 icons weren't available together, then it will show
>   default.jpg otherwise it won't show default.jpg, How to make it?

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code: (replace you above mention code and try with this)

```
<td>
    <?php 
        if((!empty($rec->telegram) && !empty($rec->google_plus) && !empty($rec->instagram) && !empty($rec->facebook))) { ?>
            <img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url()."social/telegram.jpg"; ?>" />
            <img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url()."social/g.jpg"; ?>" />
            <img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url()."social/insta.jpg"; ?>" />
            <img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url()."social/f.jpg"; ?>" /><?php 
         }else{ 
            $defaultSrc = base_url()."social/default.jpg";
            for($i=0; $i < 4;$i++){
                echo '<img class="social" src="'.$defaultSrc.'"/>';
            }
        } 
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Doesn't address the asker's question: "If all of 4 icons weren't available together, then it will show default.jpg"

Comment: As I mentioned, If all 4 icons weren't available then it will show default.jpg,.

Comment: I added your code, just its showing default.jpg, it doesn't show available icons

Comment: Yes all of them are available, in table, based on row and columns, some of  them are available and some of them not, but currently based on your code, even all available icons not showing, it's just showing default.jpg for available and unavailable icons.

Comment: if some are not available and for that unavailable icons if you want to show default.jpg then change in script is needed..!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
<? php
$icons_available = (!empty($rec - > telegram) &&
  !empty($rec - > google_plus) &&
  !empty($rec - > instagram) &&
  !empty($rec - > facebook)
); ?>
< td >
  <? php
if (!$icons_available) { ?> < img class = "social"
  src = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/default.jpg" / >
    <? php
} else if ($rec - > telegram) { ?> < a href = "<?php echo $rec->telegram;  ?>" > < img class = "social"
  src = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/telegram.jpg" / > < /a>
    <?php }else if($rec->google_pluse){ ?><a href="<?php echo $rec->google_pluse;  ?>"><img class="social" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>social/g.jpg " /></a>
    <?php }else if($rec->instagram){ ?><a href=" <? php echo $rec - > instagram; ?> "><img class="
  social " src=" <? php echo base_url(); ?> social / insta.jpg " /></a>
    <?php }else if($rec->facebook){ ?><a href=" <? php echo $rec - > facebook; ?> "><img class="
  social " src=" <? php echo base_url(); ?> social / f.jpg " /><?php } ?></a>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather use a PHP switch http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php You will then put default.jpg in the default section of the switch.